# Table content held within a div will not print over several pages

Tags: css, printing

I have some tabular content that is held within a div thus..

```
<div class="someDiv">
   <table>
       <tr>...</tr>
       ....
       ....
       <tr>...</tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

When I print using a print stylesheet with all items set to `float:none !important;` and `height:auto !important;` the table will only print one page worth of information as opposed to about 10 or so.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to add

```
* { overflow:visible ! important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as CSS syntax?

I see in this [old article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) (where I first heard of this) they have **a space between the exclamation point and the word important.**

I also see a space [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/) (section 3.1 is about important).

Does your CSS code have that space?

Comment: Good spot, the change didn't fix that but I will remember to put the space in from now on.